# Python Nested List Comprehensions to create a matrix

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm new to list comprehensions and would like to replicate the following code below in for loops into a nested list comprehension.

```
 master = []
 inner = []
 for x in range(1,8):
     inner = []
     for y in range(1,x+1):
         inner.append(str(x*y).rjust(2))

     master.append(inner)

for m in master:
    print ' '.join(m)
```

The output looks like this:

```
  1
  2  4
  3  6  9
  4  8 12 16
  5 10 15 20 25
  6 12 18 24 30 36
  7 14 21 28 35 42 49
```

I was thinking something like:

```
 test =  [  
    [str(x*y).rjust(2) for x in range(1,8)] 
    for y in range(1,x+1) 
 ] 
 for t in test:
     print ' '.join(t)
```

But I get a traceback error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "python", line 3, in <module>
 NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Any python experts care to point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you realize that your `master` loop goes from 1 up to and including 8, but your logic causes you to "forget" the last row?

Comment: @Austin Hastings...thank you . I did not notice that but I've updated the routine above to correct so it does not "forget" the last row anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switched your `for` loops.  Just switch them back:

```
test =  [   
    [str(x*y).rjust(2) for y in range(1,x+1)]
    for x in range(1,8) 
] 
for t in test:
    print ' '.join(t)
```

The reason for that is that you want a new list once for each `x`, but the inner list has as many numbers as `y`.

Comment: Thanks! The order of the for loops was not intuitive for me.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the following nested list comprehension:

```
answer = [[i*j for i in range(1, j+1)] for j in range(1, 8)]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[1],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 6, 9],
 [4, 8, 12, 16], 
 [5, 10, 15, 20, 25], 
 [6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36], 
 [7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]]
```

Comment: Thanks! That works too. Much appreciated. The order of the for loops was not intuitive. Seems that in range(1, j+1) that j would not yet be in scope but clearly it is.

Answer (score 2):

> Python 3

```
print("\n".join([" ".join([str(x*y) for y in range(1,x+1)]) for x in range(1,8) ]))
```

> Python 2

```
print "\n".join([" ".join([str(x*y) for y in range(1,x+1)]) for x in range(1,8) ])
```

> Two Step Process.
>
> Join the list by space viz. output '1', '2 4', '3 6 9' etc
>
> Join the resultant list by '\n' and print the result